# Users are not reciveing GCM push notifications after updating app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Currently, my android app is live on play store.Currently, I have integrated GCM in it and uploaded it on play store. The problem is newly downloaded users are getting a notification on the app but previous users those who have updated the app to current version are not receiving notifications.
Is there any configuration for GCM I have to do it on play store?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the documentation for [Setting up GCM for Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) and see if you missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

When application is updated then you should invalidate existing registration id again because it is not guaranteed to work with the new version.

So for that you need to check application version on start up if it changed then you need to registration process again.

Google recommend to re-register to GCM when launching the app after a new version is installed to overcome a bug that might cause the device to get unregistered if a GCM message arrives while the new version is installed.

**[More details](https://medium.com/@murki/gcm-push-notifications-registration-done-right-7aba759d1d55#.jx85c7dsj)**